# StickNFind Bluetooth GATT Profiles

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does anyone know what Bluetooth LE GATT profiles/services StickNFind is using?

I am working on BLE project on Android with other products. I have not purchased any StickNFind stickers. I just want to know a bit more about these stickers before considering to  have the app supporting it.

Many thanks.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but please consider that the company is dodgy and the tags are really not very good. http://www.eevblog.com/forum/crowd-funded-projects/sticknfind-bluetooth-low-energy-(ble)-tracking-tags/

Answer (score 2):

I've already bougth one of these stickers and I'm working with.
To answer your question, I don't have the LE GATT Server complete table of all the services that it supports but there's an interesting app on Iphones call "BLE Utility" which provides you the complete list of those services (supported by the stickers) with their UUIDs
There is the link:https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/ble-utility/id606210918?mt=8
Hoping it will help you
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I recently found an app for android: "nRF Master Control Panel (BLE)"

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp

It helped to me learn lot about the stick-n-find tags. I still haven't been able to map the uuids to anything useful... but this app at least listed them out and can pull/push data to the attributes.

EDIT: 
I reached out to the manufacture and they have an SDK (and sample app), you have to sign up for a free account to get access:

https://bluvision.com/developer/beeks-beacons-sdk/
http://bluvision.com/developer/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/09/Android-SDK.zip