# Reading Stick'n'Find BLE beacons

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, battery, characteristics

I am using a generic BLE plugin for PhoneGap when developing a BLE enabled application. It gives me beacons identification and RSSI, but reading more advanced attributes like battery status or TX power require specific communication with a beacon, which is manufacture dependant as far as I know. Does anybody of you know, how to read for example the battery status from Stick'n'Find BLE beacons. So far I have been able to discover,  that it's necessary to connect to the beacon and after it a characteristic has to be read. But here, I am lost.

Marek

Answer (score 0):

You must use a manufacturer SDK to do this.  One user reported:

> I reached out to the manufacture and they have an SDK (and sample app), you have to sign up for a free account to get access: https://bluvision.com/developer/beeks-beacons-sdk/ http://bluvision.com/developer/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/09/Android-SDK.zip

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26424648/1461050

Comment: Sorry, I highly doubt anybody has created a phone gap solution for this beacon's proprietary fields.

Comment: Just description of the protocol would be nice. As generic BLE plugin has all communication functions, I could implement it myself ....